# How to create Side-by-side plots of Taylor diagram and ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

I have two plots i.e. Taylor diagram and ggplot.
I would like to plot them in a single plot (side-by-side).
I tried `library(patchwork)`, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
library(tidyr)
library(openair)
dat=data.frame(
  a=runif(10),
  b=runif(10)
)
dat = gather(dat, columnNames, values)
colnames(dat)=c("model", "x")
dat$b=runif(20)
plot1= ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = b, group = model,
                color = model, shape = model)) + 
  geom_point( aes(colour = model)) 
#plot-2
dates <- seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"),as.Date("2015-12-31"),1)
obs=runif(365)
mod=runif(365)
model=rep(c("model1","model2"),times=c(150,215))
mod.dat <- data.frame(dates,obs,mod,model)
TaylorDiagram(mod.dat, obs = "obs", mod = "mod", group = "model")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about with `gridExtra::grid.arrange`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(openair)
dat=data.frame(
  a=runif(10),
  b=runif(10)
)
dat = gather(dat, columnNames, values)
colnames(dat)=c("model", "x")
dat$b=runif(20)
plot1= ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = b, group = model,
                       color = model, shape = model)) + 
  geom_point( aes(colour = model)) 

#plot-2
dates <- seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"),as.Date("2015-12-31"),1)
obs=runif(365)
mod=runif(365)
model=rep(c("model1","model2"),times=c(150,215))
mod.dat <- data.frame(dates,obs,mod,model)
plot2 <- TaylorDiagram(mod.dat, obs = "obs", mod = "mod", group = "model")

gridExtra::grid.arrange(plot1, plot2$plot, ncol = 2)
```

[image]